# Parse 10^-7 using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to parse a set of dates using java's `SimpleDateFormat`. For example:

```
2015-05-05T13:53:00.0000000
2015-05-05T09:38:00.0000000
2015-05-05T00:33:00.0000000
2015-05-04T18:18:00.0000000
```

This is the pattern I have so far `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'0000'` but it is causing a parse exception with these dates. How can I parse these dates with SimpleDateFormat?

I know I could probably remove the trailing zeros but I would prefer not to manipulate the date strings before parsing.

Here is an example test for this problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Test {
    public static Date getDate(String value, String format) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return df.parse(value);
    }

    public static List<Date> getDates(List<String> values, String format) throws ParseException {
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        for(String s : values) {
            dates.add(getDate(s, format));
        }
        return dates;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        dates.add("2015-05-05T13:53:00.0000000");
        dates.add("2015-05-05T09:38:00.0000000");
        dates.add("2015-05-05T00:33:00.0000000");
        dates.add("2015-05-04T18:18:00.0000000");

        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'0000'";
        try {
            getDates(dates, format);
        } catch(ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception parsing with " + format);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the Java code you used?

Comment: Ideally provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: I am quite sure encountering that S scans a number turned into ms, added to the date. Caused troubles at that time, as ms != fractional seconds.

Comment: I added code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregard milliseconds:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

The problem being that S is specified as ms, where in reality it is the fractional part of seconds. Now a number is scanned after the `.` and added as milliseconds to the date.

Alternatively java 8 merits a research.

As you are using the ISO standard. java 8 becomes quite terse:

```
    LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-05T13:53:00.9990000");
```

Which again would yield "2015-05-05T13:53:00.999" - Java 8 solved the ms interpretation!

Comment: S is added to the date. I tried it with .9999999 and it added almost 3 hours to the date.

Comment: Also I think the 7 digits could come from the timezone being appended to the date.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date date = sdf.parse("2015-05-04T18:18:00.0000000");
    System.out.println(date);
```

Above code gives `Mon May 04 18:18:00 CEST 2015`.

The SimpleDateFormater always parses from front to the end of the format (you're giving him).
So,the SimpleDateFormater doesn't bother with the extra zero's.

Comment: If there are ms, then ".9990000" would probably even change the day.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the 4 extra zero's.
Because, with or without them it gives the same result.

But,I'm not quite sure what your point is.

Comment: I think S scans a number, and turns that in ms. As you have a compiler, are you sure?